# Appropriate use of FPS count code in Unity and Games in general?

Tags: performance, count, unity-game-engine, frame, frame-rate

So I've been working on a project in Unity, and after writing this very simple code, I started wondering about how computers with faster and slower frame rates would generate slightly different speeds.

The code:

```
for (i = 0; i < distance ; i++) transform.Translate(speed*Time.deltaTime,0,0);
```

Mostly, I was wondering if in slower computers, the moving object wouldn't move as far, and if I took out the deltaTime multiplication, would the object appear to be moving slower in a slower computer than on one with a faster FPS count.

If so, how would I solve this problem, if it's a problem at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of using the Time.DeltaTime in the equation is to remove this fear. Remember that the [Time.DeltaTime](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) is not analogous to the FPS your machine can produce, with that you can produce animations/movements and in general anything time dependent and frame rate independent.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Update() function (of a Monobehaviour object) then you shouldn't need to worry about the object not traveling as far.